# Deploying Django + Angular to EB without using django templates in production

Tags: django, angular, amazon-s3

I've been reading a million answers in this subject but I can't find a solution that works.

I have a Django DRF backend that is used for all the API calls and a separate Angular(5) front-end project. The Django backend is deployed to Elastic Beanstalk and is working properly.

All I want to do is to deploy the angular frontend without needing to add template tags to the htmls. Better yet I don't want to change anything in the built dist Angular folder.

I see there are several approaches - As far as I can understand the best one would be to serve the index.html through a regular Django url and then expose all the dist folder (the static files).

I achieved the first part using:

```
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
    url(r'^(?P<path>.*)/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
]
```

and defining the dist folder as a template folder in settings.py:

```
ANGULAR_APP_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'client/dist')

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [ANGULAR_APP_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Currently, I define an s3 bucket to hold all static files. 'collectstatic' runs when I deploy the code and puts all the static files in the right location on s3, including the files in dist, because I added this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    ANGULAR_APP_DIR,
]
```

I can't figure out how to serve all the other static files (js, css assets) from the base url ("/") which is the location that the Angular app is expecting it to be in.

I'm not sure if I should try redirecting the calls Through Django urls to the s3 bucket, or if I should do it totally separate from Django with routes on s3. 
What would be a better approach and how is it done?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand why you've made ANGULAR_APP_DIR a Django template dir. As you said, Django and Angular templates are completely separate.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I did that so that Django will find index.html when it runs the url patterns I mentioned above. Without it, it doesn't even serve the index.html. But I'm happy to hear about any different approach that works.

Comment: But does your index.html contain any Django template tags, or just Angular ones?

Comment: My approach is to treat the Angular app as a separate app, that is deployed separately as well (it is, after all, a bunch of some static js ,css etc. files)

Comment: @DanielRoseman my index.html does not contain any Django template tags. Yes, it's not necessary to serve it through Django, It's just recommended many times in different posts like this one: https://www.techiediaries.com/django-angular-cli/ . How would you do it?

Comment: @zm0 separte app on EB? You mean deploy it separetly to elastic beanstalk or s3 and make them totally disconnected? Might you have a good resourse of how to do that?

Comment: You would probably want to serve the app on `/` , then define a proxy for a location like `/api` (the proxy configuration would forward these requests to django). nginx configurations can be found for those setups. 
Do not have experience in beanstalk, but seemingly proxy setups with nginx are possible as well, maybe this for a start: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-platform-proxy.html